# XLSX Export Example for bokeh data table

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to export my interactive bokeh data table to an xlsx excel table. I am able to replicate the csv export example on github https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/main/examples/server/app/export_csv with my data. However, I want to export my data as an xlsx format and not csv. I am not very familiar with Java Script so I do not know what I need to change in the download.js file so that when pressing the export buttom the data gets exported as xlsx format.

Thank you for your help!